# @csrf_exempt does not work on generic view based class

Tags: python, django

```
class ChromeLoginView(View):

     def get(self, request):
          return JsonResponse({'status': request.user.is_authenticated()})

     @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
     def post(self, request):
          username = request.POST['username']
          password = request.POST['password']
          user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
          if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                     login(request, user)
                     return JsonResponse({'status': True})
          return JsonResponse({'status': False})
```

I am expecting that the post does stopped by csrf, but it return 403 error.

But if remove that decorator and do this in the URLConf

```
url(r'^chrome_login/', csrf_exempt(ChromeLoginView.as_view()), name='chrome_login'),
```

it will work.

What happened here? didn't it supposed to work, because I guess that's what method_decorator do.
I'm using python3.4 and django1.7.1

Any advice would be great.

Comment: You should look into the django_braces...

Comment: It's super awesome! Especially since you can simply add the [CsrfExemptMixin](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/form.html#csrfexemptmixin) to your view to make this work. It's almost like cheating...

Comment: In my use case I am not using a form, so how can I still include a csrf token in my application? Like I am creating APIs hence a UI doesn't come into picture. So how can I make sure that CSRF token is still passed?

Comment: These answers won't work for DRF. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf

Answer (score 145, accepted):

As @knbk said, this is the `dispatch()` method that must be decorated.

Since Django 1.9, [you can use the `method_decorator` directly on a class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ChromeLoginView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'status': request.user.is_authenticated()})

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return JsonResponse({'status': True})
        return JsonResponse({'status': False})
```

This avoids overriding the `dispatch()` method only to decorate it.

Answer (score 101):

You need to decorate the `dispatch` method for `csrf_exempt` to work. What it does is set an `csrf_exempt` attribute on the view function itself to `True`, and the middleware checks for this on the (outermost) view function. If only a few of the methods need to be decorated, you still need to use `csrf_exempt` on the `dispatch` method, but you can use `csrf_protect` on e.g. `put()`. If a `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS` or `TRACE` HTTP method is used it won't be checked whether you decorate it or not.

```
class ChromeLoginView(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ChromeLoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'status': request.user.is_authenticated()})

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return JsonResponse({'status': True})
        return JsonResponse({'status': False})
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for Mixins to match your needs, then you can create a CSRFExemptMixin and extend that in your view no need of writing above statements in every view:

```
class CSRFExemptMixin(object):
   @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
   def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(CSRFExemptMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

After that Extend this in your view like this.

```
class ChromeLoginView(CSRFExemptMixin, View):
```

You can extend that in any view according to your requirement,  That's reusability! :-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

[Django braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form.html#csrfexemptmixin) provides a `CsrfExemptMixin` for this.

```
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin

class ChromeLoginView(CsrfExemptMixin, View):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired results directly in the urls.py file related to the specific views.py app.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [path('validate-email', csrf_exempt(EmailValidationView.as_view())]
```

Then just use your class in your views.py normally.