# Delete via AJAX results in CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django

**Django 1.10**

DetailView renders "detail.html".

In "detail.html" I place "Delete" button. In other words, I want users to be able to press "Delete" exactly from "detail.html" when they see the object itself.

So, on pressing "Delete" button I call FrameDelete via AJAX.

Could you help me understand why I get the error: **CSRF token missing or incorrect.**

```
class Frame(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                             null=False,
                             blank=False,
                             default="",
                             unique=True,
                             verbose_name="Заголовок")
    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse("frame:frame_delete", kwargs=self.get_kwargs())

class FrameDelete(ActionDeleteMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Frame
    success_url = reverse_lazy("empty")
    template_name = 'general/ajax/ajax_confirm_delete.html'

class ActionDeleteMixin():
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ActionDeleteMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["action"] = self.object.get_delete_url()
        return context
```

**js**

```
    function post_delete(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "{{ object.get_delete_url }}",
            success: redirect_to_frame_list,
            error: fail
        });
    }

function fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    debugger;   
}
```

**ajax_confirm_delete.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ action }}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>Are you surely want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
        <input id="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**In the browser when inspecting element in Chrome:**

```
<form action="/frame/18/delete/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="bHZxf62Oa9WrapuacCm8gLVNlY2nJHllfwqPsAHoPO0RS8z8NnhMSv5tnIFQZKPP">
        <p>Are you surely want to delete "18: Michael's news"?</p>
        <input id="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>
```

**

**In the browser when stop at the debugger breakpoint in fail function**

```
"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


</div>

<div id="info">
  <h2>Help</h2>

    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
    </pre>


  <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  <a
  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/">Django's
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>

    <li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template's <a
    href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a>
    method.</li>

    <li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token
    %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that
    targets an internal URL.</li>

    <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
    <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>
    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>

    <li>The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser
    tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the
    page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.</li>
  </ul>

  <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG =
  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,
  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>

  <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the [csrf_exempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315592/csrf-exempt-does-not-work-on-generic-view-based-class) or generate the [csrf token with ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax)