# Parsing POST request - object() takes no parameters

Tags: django

I try to access post request and check if user with email that is in post request already exist. When I try to send data to endpoint, I get error

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

my views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
class CheckIfEmailAvailable():

   @csrf_exempt
   def check(request):
      email = request.POST.get("email")
      if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
         return Response({'status': 'not available'})
```

my url.py
    url(r'^api/checkmail/', CheckIfEmailAvailable, name='check'),

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case better to use function in the url

```
from your_app.views import check

url(r'^api/checkmail/', check, name='check')
```

and your view will be like this (only function)

```
@csrf_exempt
def check(request):
  email = request.POST.get("email")
  if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
     return JsonResponse({'status': 'not available'})
```

Also FYI if you want to use `@csrf_exempt` with classes you should use `dispatch`, you can get more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315592/csrf-exempt-does-not-work-on-generic-view-based-class)

Example of JsonResponse

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def your_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

Comment: it says "/Users/me/Documents/Django/datingproject/datingproject/urls.py", line 32, in <module>
    url(r'^api/checkmail/', check, name='check'),
NameError: name 'check' is not defined

Comment: You should import your view. Please add "from your_app.views import check"

Comment: now it says .accepted_renderer not set on Response :(

Comment: Sure you should use JsonResponse instaed of Response if you want to send dict. Added example to response

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit your class your generic django views for this to work. Url patterns expect a callable that can accept request (with args and kwargs) and return response. `View.as_view` class method returns a callable for you.

```
# In views file
from django.views.generic import View

...

class CheckIfEmailAvailable(View):

      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          return self.check(request) # or something else depends on your use case

# In urls file
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
...
url(r'^api/checkmail/', csrf_exempt(CheckIfEmailAvailable.as_view()), name='check'),
```

Moreover `csrf_exempt` decorator won't work (out of box) on classes, neither on bound methods for that matter. Better way should be to use them in urls.

Comment: now it complains url(r'^api/checkmail/', CheckIfEmailAvailable.as_view(), name='check'),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Comment: remove csrf_exempt class decoration

Comment: Please upvote and mark it as correct answer if it helped

Comment: now it complains about csrf in browser when i try to send request to test email

Comment: sorry I missed in your reply. actually it says @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
NameError: name 'method_decorator' is not defined

Comment: If that doesn't work, use csrf_exempt in urls instead.

Comment: now it says NameError: name 'csrf_exempt' is not defined

Comment: Ofcourse you need to import it. `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

Answer (score 0):

If you had posted the full traceback, you would see that the error does not come from parsing the request; Django does not even get nearly that far.

You can't use a class as a view like that. You should have `check` as a standalone function, without a class, and refer to it directly in your urls.

Django does support class-based views, but they have a very specific structure, need to inherit from the proper base class, and be referenced in the urls.py in a specific way.