# AJAX call returns CSRF Failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, typescript, csrf

Iam doing an ajax call in Typescript which calls an internal Webservice. All endpoints whit "GET" are working, but whit "POST" it says

> "403 Forbidden" - "detail: CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set"

Things i tried to fix the issue:

> - Followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/csrf/
> - Tryed to delete 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
> - Tryed @csrf_exempt

Nothing of this has worked, everytime still the same error occurs.

Here is my code in Typescript:

```
sendMessage(message, receiverId){
    let self = this;
    var message_obj = "{\"id\":\""+ GUID.generateGUID() +"\",\"message\":\""+ message +"\",\"receiverId\":\""+ receiverId + "\",\"moddate\":\""+ Date.now() +"\"}";
    var message_json = JSON.parse(message_obj);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/chat/message/",
        data:{"message_object":message_json},
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    })
}
```

This is an example of an working ajax call:

```
getMessages(){
    let self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/chat/message/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            response = JSON.stringify(response);
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT:

Here is where i tryed to use csrf_exempt:

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from chat_api import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^message/$', csrf_exempt(views.ChatMessageAPIEndpoint.as_view())),
    url(r'^message/(?P<commit>([0-9a-fA-F])+)', csrf_exempt(views.ChatMessageAPIEndpoint.as_view())),
    url(r'^devicekey/(?P<devid>([\w+-:])+)', views.DeviceAPIEndpoint.as_view()),
    url(r'^devicekey/$', views.DeviceAPIEndpoint.as_view()),
    url(r'^contacts/$', views.ContactAPIEndpoint.as_view()),
    url(r'^read/$', views.ReadStatusEndpoint.as_view()),
]
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
    @csrf_exempt
    @need_post_parameters([PARAM_MESSAGE_OBJ])
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST.get(PARAM_MESSAGE_OBJ)

        try:
            message_obj = json.loads(data)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(error_json("Could not parse JSON"))
...
```

Comment: Show how you attempted to use `@csrf_exempt`. [mcve]

Comment: The django docs has an example of how to include the CSRF token in ajax requests using `jQuery.ajax()`. You have to include a `X-CSRFToken`  header. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: @HåkenLid I tryed: csrf_exempt(views.ChatMessageAPIEndpoint.as_view()) and i tryed to set it as annotation in front of the Endpoint methods

Comment: Also i tryed the Django docs example but it also doestn work! I debugged the Django docs example but on the part: "if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {" it goes out and returns null!

Comment: Include **in the question** the actual code where you did `csrf_exempt(views.ChatMessageAPIEndpoint.as_view())`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views

Comment: Your client side code has to **extract the token from a cookie** and **include the token in each ajax request**. The header should look something like this: `X-CSRFToken: i8XNjC4b8KVok4uw5RftR38Wgp2BFwql`

Comment: @HåkenLid I only got a session cookie. As i said it fails at `if (document.cookie && document.cookie !=="" `. If i type document.cookie directly into the Browser console, it simpy returns ""!

Comment: Here's an question about how to use `csrf_exempt` with class based views. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315592/csrf-exempt-does-not-work-on-generic-view-based-class

Comment: The cookie might be missing because you have disabled it somewhere. You can use the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator on the view where you need the cookie. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie

Comment: You have to choose whether you want csrf protection or not. Disabling it some places and enabling it elsewhere will only lead to a mess. The default is to have the csrf cookie included everywhere.

Comment: Ive tried it but it also doesnt work. I tryed to debug the Python script and it seems like it doesnt even comes there. Could it be, that the error is thrown on the Client side? In Typescript etc?

Comment: I want to enable it but all i try to make it working fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake and i will post it here for equal errors:

My Classes in **Views.py** where using **"Oauth2APIView"**!
Changing it into **"View"** did solve the problem for me!