# How to send POST request to Django REST API using python requests

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have a simple rest api which I want to send a post request to using requests.

My url pattern is this:

```
url(r'^$', views.ProductList.as_view())
```

Inside my view I have:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print('THIS IS A POST REQUEST')
        queryset = [product.name for product in Product.objects.all()]
        return Response(queryset)
```

And I am trying to send a post request using:

```
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/')
```

However this returns a 403, and the print statement isn't printed. I have done some research and I think it may have something to do with the CSRF token not being there but i'm not to sure how to add that. Does anybody know how I can get the post request to work?

I'm using python 3.6.3 and Django 1.10

Comment: add the urls. your endpoint needs to be a url connected to the view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315592/csrf-exempt-does-not-work-on-generic-view-based-class csrf exempt your view

Comment: @harshil9968 Thanks. I've added as they've said but still getting 403

Comment: 403 can also mean that the view expects a logged-in user. Is that the case in your setup?

Comment: @Ralf No its not the case, Ive updated my question with the url pattern

Comment: shouldn't your endpoint be `requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/products/')` ?

Comment: @BernardParah sorry that /products shouldn't be there. I went into the Rest Framework Permissions and changed it to AllowAny. Not sure if that's the best way to do it but it now works

Comment: No it's not the best way. CSRF exempt should work 100%.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov what could be causing the 403 then

Comment: what is the settings for `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` for Rest Framework in your settings file?

Comment: @BernardParah ive now changed it to AllowAny and it works, but this isn't the best way to do it

Comment: @AndreyShipilov what do u recommend I should put my permissions as

Comment: If you don't put anything it's `AllowAny`, from docs. If you need permissions — put needed ones.

Answer (score 1):

ListAPIView is meant for only listing your products hence the POST requests are forbidden.

> ### ListAPIView
>
> Used for read-only endpoints to represent a collection of model instances.
>
> taken from [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview)

You should use ListCreateAPIView:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    List all products or create a product.
    """
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

Comment: I'm still getting the 403. If I use this what permissions should I have for it. I don't really need any permissions in general on my site, so anything which would allow the post request to be sent to the API.

Comment: Where exactly are you sending the post request from? Are you still using your self-defined post function? Why are you using `queryset = [product.name for product in Product.objects.all()]` for a post request? If you want to create a product in your backend, simply use ListCreateAPIView and send the necessary data according to your serializer using the class above.

Comment: im sending the post request using python requests. I understand what you are saying about the queryset variable, but I'm still confused about how I would go about adding to the database then by using ListCreateAPIView

Comment: is the python request from another server? Why do you need an API if not. You need to send a post request with form data that contains the json representation of your ProductSerializer (should be a ModelSerializer else you need to manually create the object when receiving the data)

Comment: right now its all from the same computer, however once it's finished I intend to put it on a server which is why I need the API. I am sending it a post request using request.post(the URL, json={data here}) this command is just running through a python shell on my computer

Comment: your parameter seems to be wrong, should be data instead of json. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476373/simple-url-get-post-function-in-python for examples on how to send json data with post

Comment: im using json and that seems to work fine. As some people have suggested in the comments I have added a csrf exempt and changed the permissions to AllowAny which gets rid of the 403 and he post request works fine. But apparently I shouldnt, or is bad practice to put AllowAny in the permissions