# Python Requests library to fill out option list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, python-requests

I'm trying to fill out a web form using python requests. Does anyone know the correct syntax when there is a drop down (option list)?

I can successfully post to the text boxes on the form, but not the option list

```
import requests

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/recoater/new/'
payload = {
   'data': '40',
   'machine': '"1">MachineA<',
}

r = requests.post(URL, data=payload)
print (r)
print(r.text)
```

Returns this:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of 
the available choices.</li></ul>
<p><label for="id_machine">Machine:</label> <select name="machine" required 
id="id_machine">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="1">MachineA</option>
```

Comment: You should use the *value*, so `'1'` for machine 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a `<select>..</select>`, the `POST` data sends the `value=".."` of the selected `<option>`, so in case you want `MachineA`, you should send it with `'machine': '1'`, as payload:

import requests

```
URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/recoater/new/'
payload = {
   'data': '40',
   'machine': '1',
}

r = requests.post(URL, data=payload)
print (r)
print(r.text)
```

The Django forms (or other mechanisms that handle the request) have logic in place to map this value back to the machine that is associated with this value: after all, the text in the option is just a *textual representation* of the `Machine` object, it can contain a lot of (extra) data that is not displayed (or is displayed, but in a non-structured way).

So a browser will for a webpage:

```
<select name="machine" required id="id_machine">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="1">MachineA</option>
</select>
```

Send in the `POST` data an entry that associates the `name` of the `<select>` (here `'machine'`) that is associated with the `value` of the option picked (here `''` or `'1'`). Just like a `<input name="data" type="text">` has a `value` parameter as well that is set to the value you enter in the textfield.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that worked! However.. I am getting a pretty huge error stack now. Although it is successfully posting the data to the server, this error message is beyond my skills.
stack: https://pastebin.com/t2AhSN05

Comment: @MattG: do you have "the source code of the view" behind this request. Looks like either the server does a large amount of work, and the connection has timed out, or even forced a disconnect): https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4413

Comment: @MattG: what if you use `method_decorator`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27315856/67579

Comment: Perhaps this should branch off into a separate question. I think it has something to do with the CSRF decorator. I tried to remove this from the view, and add it to the urls.py instead, and am still getting the same error.
It is strange becuase the post request is successful, it is something that happens after the POST.

Comment: Getting closer I think.. after adding the method_decorator I am now getting:
https://pastebin.com/JAr14NaZ

Comment: @MattG: it looks to me that now the `csrf` is required again, so the POST is not processed (since the CSRF check fails)

Comment: Thanks again for the help @Willem Van Onsem. I changed my view from a class based view, to a function based view, and this solved the problem. Just don't ask me how! Django magic I guess.