# Django - csrf cookie not set

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I've been trying for hours to send a POST request to an endpoint in my Django application from my separated VueJS frontend using Axios. The problem with my code is that whatever i try i will always get `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`, and i can't use `@crsf_exempt`.

I tried every possible solution i found, from changing headers names in my Axios request to setting CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to False, nothing seems to solve this problem.

Here is my request:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  console.log(cookieValue)
  return cookieValue;
}

function req(){

  this.csrf_token = getCookie('csrftoken')

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/testreq/',

    data: {
      //Some data here
    },

    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRFToken': this.csrf_ftoken }
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  });

},
```

The token is being sent but the outcome is always the same. The Django app is using Django-Rest-Framework too, i don't know if that's the problem.

Here is some of my settings.py (for development):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
    'xsrfheadername',
    'xsrfcookiename',
    'content-type',
    'csrftoken',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'X-CSRFTOKEN',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

I don't know what else can i try to solve this problem, any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The Default Authentication Scheme in [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) is

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Session Authentication requires a CSRF Token when you make POST requests unless exempted using `@csrf_exempt`

**CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE** in [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE) only ensures that CSRF Tokens are sent via HTTPS

To Fix Your Issue, you can change **DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES** from the default to

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Once you switch to TokenAuthentication you'll have to exchange the user's credentials for an Auth token and use that Token For Subsequent requests

[Django Rest Framework's](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) guide on Token Authentication

You can also take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315592/csrf-exempt-does-not-work-on-generic-view-based-class) here to use `@csrf_exempt` on class based views

Comment: Thank you a lot, but unfortunately Session Authentication is required on this project, i thought of using token but i would rather go with Session for now

Comment: You may want to take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19008548/14559369) incase you have any of the options turned on.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it's a problem caused by 'cross-domain', you cannot set cookie or store it in browser generated by backend localhost:8000 through frontend localhost:8080. If you want to store or modify cookie you can only access localhost:8000.

You can use Nginx as reverse proxy to solve the problem, Here is the video for details
https://youtube.com/watch?v=VeDms9GPaLw

Comment: Please don't say "You can do x" and then post a link to a video that isn't in English to explain how to do x.